# particular discount

Tags: discount

Good evening,
I'm really bored because I've seen a lot of magento extensions without solutions for my problem. :( Is a simple problem, I know, and I hope that someone can help me..
I would like to know if there is an extention that creates a discount dedicated to a group of users (user input from the backend will happen anyway - I know, I can do this with magento basic) but it is locked if the total of the orders placed during the calendar year is more than 1000 €.

For example:
we have a partner company, all the employers can register in our shop online by sending a mail to our store manager.
The store manager create a list/group "Partner company" and he place all the employers that enjoied the promo with us.
The group "Partner Company" had 40% discount.
But I need an extension that give me the opportunity to block the discount if the single client had made ​​purchases in the year up to a total of 1000 (order 1 is 400 order 2 is 25... order 7 is 30€, the total is 999.99 so "stop" discount).

I hope I explained well the problem and I apologize for my bad English  (also for my ignorance) ;)

Thank you so much for everyone.
Have a nice day
xoxo
Elisa

Comment: Elisa can I just say I'm a big fan of how polite you are, welcome to Magento.stackexchange, did you solve your issue in the end? Also your English is very good! No need for apologies

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved pretty easily:

- Create a cart price rule for the customer group with the discount
- Create a cronjob (or alternatively an observer which comes after an order is placed) which checks the order amounts for the customer group and if it is above the threshold, the cart price rule is deactivated.

Should be doable to be programmed within a day.